# turtle.bgpic() leads to Tk exception

Tags: python-3.x

First year CS student here, a project I'm working on is being stalled by a seemingly simple error when trying to set a background picture for a Turtle window:

This:

```
def test():
    turtle.bgpic("image.gif")
```

consistently returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Wesley\Desktop\RISK.py", line 17, in <module>
    createGameMap()
  File "C:\Users\Wesley\Desktop\RISK.py", line 7, in createGameMap
    t.bgpic("Risk01.gif")
  File "C:\Python 3.4.2\lib\cTurtle.py", line 2564, in bgpic
    return self.getScreen().bgpic(picname)
  File "C:\Python 3.4.2\lib\cTurtle.py", line 1012, in bgpic
    self._setbgpic(self._bgpic, self._bgpics[picname])
  File "C:\Python 3.4.2\lib\cTurtle.py", line 532, in _setbgpic
    self.cv.itemconfig(item, image=image)
  File "<string>", line 1, in itemconfig
  File "C:\Python 3.4.2\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2416, in itemconfigure
    return self._configure(('itemconfigure', tagOrId), cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Python 3.4.2\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1310, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage2" doesn't exist
```

Please help me resolve this error, I'm totally at a loss for an explanation to even begin troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using a relative reference for the image, is "image.gif" in the same directory as --> "C:\Users\Wesley\Desktop\RISK.py" your Risk.py file?

Comment: Yes, it is. Both are saved to my desktop at the moment.